# AndroidAnnotations Rest client DAX exception (UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION using org.springframework.android)

Tags: android, gradle, spring-android

I have an UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION in DAX when I try to add Spring Template (org.springframework.android) as a Gradle dependency.

Here is the REST documentation:
https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API#restservice

I don't see any information about additional dependencies. That's why I added the missed dependency as in another post:
[AndroidAnnotations Rest SourceHttpMessageConverter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556560/androidannotations-rest-sourcehttpmessageconverter-error)

```
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
```

For me, it doesn't work.

Could someone post a list of dependencies, or better, a full REST service client example?

Comment: Solved. I've used Java 8. This Spring library doesn't work with Java 8 compilator. Just chaanged a compilator to Java 7